# Can't get jQuery form submit to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For some reason, when the form button is clicked, the jQuery script I wrote isn't running, does anyone know why?

```
<body>
    <form id="inputform" action="google.com">
        <text id="text">Enter Your Number:</text>
        <input id="input" name="input" type="text">
    <input id="submitArea" type="submit" value="">
    </form>
</body>
```

```
$('#inputform').submit(function() {
    window.location = "http://mysite.com/";
});
```

Yes, I imported the jQuery library and everything, I've sourced the external JS file, but I can't figure out why it still isn't working.

Comment: what do you expect to happen?

Comment: did you `import jquery`

Comment: @suhail If OP had not imported jQuery, error would have been different

Comment: @suhail I did write that I imported jQuery...

Comment: ok this is strange, may be you might wrote `id="inputform"` in any other tag. `#inputform` only select one `id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [prevent the default action from occuring](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/). You can do that by using `preventDefault` action on the event `e`. Something like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#inputform').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.location = "http://mysite.com/";
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your script is inside document ready, else you need to move the script inside `jQuery(function($){.....});

You need to prevent the default action of the submit button

```
$('#inputform').submit(function(e) {
    window.location = "http://mysite.com/";
    return false; // or call e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should not do a window.location call from inside a submit button. The data you entered in the Form's text input field wont be automatically posted to the action page if you do so.

```
<body>
<form id="inputform" action="http://mysite.com/">
    <text id="text">Enter Your Number:</text>
    <input id="input" name="input" type="text">
<input id="submitArea" type="submit" value="">
</form>
```

Comment: The problem is- I don't want it to use the action, (and I was using mysite.com as an example). The reason I'm using JS for this is that the URL of the page I'm getting depends on what the user enters in the form.